# How to Decrypt PHP encrypted image in windows phone 8 c#

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8, encryption

I am working a Stenography project, I encrypt my secret code(Text) into an image by using PHP library "class.stegano.php", below is full code of this library.

```
<?php
define('CHROME',1);
define('MULTI',2);
define('PNG',4);
class Stegano {

    function imagergbcolorat($im, $_x, $_y) {
        $rgbdest = imagecolorat($im, $_x, $_y);
        return array(($rgbdest >> 16) & 0xFF,($rgbdest >> 8) & 0xFF,$rgbdest & 0xFF);
    }

    function asc2bin($temp) {
        $len = strlen($temp);
        for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) $data.=$this->hexbin(sprintf("%02x",ord(substr($temp,$i,1))));
        return $data;
    }

    function hexbin($hex){
        $bin='';
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($hex);$i++) $bin.=str_pad(decbin(hexdec($hex{$i})),4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return $bin;
    } 

    # GENERATEUR DE MATRICE

    function matrice() {    
        if(strlen($this -> binaryString)%8 OR !$this -> binaryString) return false;
        $bits = strlen($this -> binaryString)/3;
        $bits += (strlen($this -> binaryString)%3);
        $bits += 48; // 2 separateur de 24 bits;
        do $separateur = $this->asc2bin(chr(rand(0,255)).chr(rand(0,255)).chr(rand(0,255)));
        while(strpos($this -> binaryString,$separateur)!==false);
        $binaryString = $separateur.($this -> binaryString).$separateur;
        $i = $area = 1; // intialisation
        do {
            $width = ceil($i*$this -> ratio);
            $height = $i++;
        }
        while($height * $width < $bits);

        if($height < $this -> height) $height = $this -> height;
        if($width < $this -> width) $width = $this -> width;

        $area = $height * $width;

        $binaryString = str_pad($binaryString, $area * 3, "0");  
        return Array("w" => $width,"h" => $height,"s"=>$binaryString,"l"=>$bits*3);
    }

    # CLASS

    function Stegano() {
        $this -> setData("Content encoded into image");
        $this -> setOrigin = CHROME;
        $this -> setColor(255,128,200);
        $this -> setRatio(1);
        $this -> imSource = false;
    }

    function setOrigin($origin=CHROME) {
        $this -> origin = $origin;
        if(file_exists($origin)) {
            $this -> imSource = imagecreatefromjpeg($origin);
            $image_width = imagesx($this -> imSource);
            $image_height = imagesy($this -> imSource);
            $this -> ratio = $image_width/$image_height;
        }
        else $this -> imSource = false;
        return $this -> origin;
    }

    function setData($data=""){
        $this -> data = $data;
        $this -> binaryString = $this -> asc2bin(gzcompress($data));
        return $this -> binaryString;
    }

    function setColor($red=128,$green=128,$blue=128) {
        $this -> red = $red;
        $this -> green = $green;
        $this -> blue = $blue;
        return Array($red,$green,$blue);
    }

    function keepSize() {
        if(!$this -> imSource) return false;
        return $this -> setSize(imagesx($this -> imSource),imagesy($this -> imSource));
    }

    function setSize($width=1,$height=1) {
        $this -> width = $width;
        $this -> height = $height;
        $this -> ratio = $width/$height;
        return Array($this -> width,$this -> height,$this -> ratio);        
    }

    function setRatio($ratio=1) {
        $this -> width = 1;
        $this -> height = 1;
        $this -> ratio = $ratio;    
    }

    function draw($output=false) {

        $matrice = $this -> matrice();

        $width = $matrice[w];
        $height = $matrice[h];
        $binaryString = $matrice[s];
        $binaryDataLenght = $matrice[l];

        $destination = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        if($this -> origin==CHROME) {
            $color = imagecolorallocate($destination,$this -> red,$this -> green,$this -> blue);
            imagefill($destination, 0, 0, $color);
        }
        elseif($this -> imSource) {
            imagecopyresampled($destination,$this -> imSource,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,imagesx($this -> imSource),imagesy($this -> imSource));
        }

        $array = Array();
        $writtenOffset = 0;

        for($_y=0;$_y<$height;$_y++) {
            $_x=-1;
            $line = substr($binaryString,$_y*$width*3,$width*3);
            if($writtenOffset>$binaryDataLenght && $this -> origin != MULTI) break;
            $pixels = str_split($line,3);
            foreach($pixels as $pixel) {
                $_x++;
                if($this -> origin == CHROME) { // Monocrhome Output
                    $r = $this -> red;
                    $g = $this -> green;
                    $b = $this -> blue;
                }
                elseif($this -> imSource) { // Image masking
                    $colors = $this->imagergbcolorat($destination, $_x, $_y);
                    $r = $colors[0];
                    $g = $colors[1];
                    $b = $colors[2];
                }
                elseif($this -> origin == MULTI) { // Multi
                    $r = mt_rand(0,255);
                    $g = mt_rand(0,255);
                    $b = mt_rand(0,255);
                }

                // Modification des 3 LSB (Last Signifiant Bit)

                $r = bindec(substr(decbin($r),0,-1).abs($pixel{0}));
                $g = bindec(substr(decbin($g),0,-1).abs($pixel{1}));
                $b = bindec(substr(decbin($b),0,-1).abs($pixel{2}));

                $color = imagecolorallocate($destination,$r,$g,$b);
                imagesetpixel($destination,$_x,$_y,$color);
            }
            $writtenOffset+=3;
        }
        $this -> imDestination = $destination;
        if($output==PNG) {
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            imagepng($this -> imDestination);
        }
        elseif($output) {
            imagepng($this -> imDestination,$output);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function getImage() {
        return $this -> imDestination;
    }

    # DECODAGE

    function decodeImageFile($file) {

        if(file_exists($file)) return $this->decodeImageRessource(imagecreatefrompng($file));
        else die("fichier introuvable");
    }

    function decodeImageRessource($im) {

        // Initialisation des variables
        $temp = "";
        $separateur = "";
        $break = false;
        $currentOctect = Array();
        $i=1;
        // Lecture du separateur

        while(strlen($separateur)<8) {
            for($_x=0;$_x<8;$_x++) {
                foreach($this->imagergbcolorat($im, $_x, $i++) as $color) {
                    if(strlen($separateur)<8) {
                        $separateur .= substr(decbin($color),-1,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        echo $separateur;

        // Découpage
        $splitedSeparateur = str_split($separateur,8);
        $currentSeparateurPart = 0;

        for($_y=0;$_y<imagesy($im);$_y++) { 
            for($_x=0;$_x<imagesx($im);$_x++) {
                // lecture d'un pixel
                foreach($this->imagergbcolorat($im, $_x, $_y) as $color) {
                    $bit = substr(decbin($color),-1,1); // LSB
                    $currentOctect[] = $bit;
                    if(count($currentOctect)==8) { // un octet complet à été detecté
                        if(join($currentOctect)==$splitedSeparateur[$currentSeparateurPart]) {
                            $currentSeparateurPart++;
                            if($currentSeparateurPart==3) {
                                if($_x!=7 || $_y!=0) {// sedonde occurrence du separateur
                                    $break = true;
                                    break;
                                }   
                                // premiere occurrence du separateur
                                // remise à zero du chercheur
                                $currentSeparateurPart=0; 
                            }
                        }
                        // le separateur n'a pas été detecter au
                        // complet, remise à zero du chercheur
                        else $currentSeparateurPart=0;
                        // démarage d'un nouvel Octet
                        $currentOctect = Array();
                    }
                    // Stokage du bit
                    $temp .= $bit;
                }
                // fin de boucle
                if($break) break;
            }
            if($break) break;
        }
        $temp = str_replace($separateur,null,$temp);
        $len = strlen($temp)-24;
        for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i+=8) {
            $sub_bin = substr($temp,$i,8);
            if(strlen($sub_bin)<8) break;
            $data.=chr(bindec($sub_bin));
        }
        return gzuncompress($data);
    }

}

?>
```

By using these methods,

```
$data = "ffffffffff";
$stegano = new Stegano();
$stegano -> setData($data);
$stegano -> setOrigin("images/image.jpg");
$stegano -> keepSize();
$stegano -> draw("images/imageencoded.png");
$stegano -> draw(PNG);
```

Now I need to decrypt this image into windows phone 8 c# Application, Is there any way to decrypt this type of encrypted image into c#?
I find this steganography decryption code but it return unexpected symbols.

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] decodedText = DecodeText(byteArrayInputImageDecode);

        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedText, 0, decodedText.Length);

        string[] split = text.Split(new Char[] { '#' });
        text = split.GetValue(0).ToString();

        TextBlockDecodeText.Text = text;


       }

    private byte[] DecodeText(byte[] Image)
    {
        int length = 0;
        int Threshold = 4096;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; ++i)
        {
            length = (length << 1) | (Image[i] & 1);
        }

        byte[] decodedText = new byte[textLength];
        for (int j = 0; j < decodedText.Length; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k, ++Threshold)
            {
                decodedText[j] = (byte)((decodedText[j] << 1) | (Image[Threshold] & 1));
            }
        }
        return decodedText;
    }
```

I need $data value in windows phone 8. Please help me
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Steganography does not refer to one strict method of hiding information, and two libraries developed by different people are very unlikely to be interoperable.

Comment: Is there any way to encrypt code in image on php side and decrypt it on windows phone 8 i.e C#?

Comment: As long as the image is not modified in a way that destroys the secret, e.g. jpeg compression, you can extract the secret by simply reversing the encryption steps. There is nothing stopping you from embedding the secret on an operating system A with programming language X and extracting it on operating system B with language Y. The place you found the php code also has the decoding part. You can translate that to an equivalent C# program.